# I need to reload my page for display CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I have used CKEDITOR 4 with two homemade plugin on my project since 1 month and everything is working  well.

I tried to do a third plugin by just following the template of my last plugin and the plugin by himself is working well.

The problem is when I go to my Index view for the second time and then go to the New view where ckeditor field is. Only the CKEDITOR field doesn't appear anymore except after reloading the page. If I go out and come back again CKEDITOR will not appear until I reload the page.

There is no error or warning on the console.

If I remove the last plugin I just made it's working correctly.
But if I keep the last plugin but remove my 2nd homemade plugin it's working well too.
Now if I remove my first homemade plugin and keep the 2nd and the last one I've got the same bug.
So I guess it's something with that but I have no idea how to debug it since there is no error or warning visible.

I even don't know which code I can give you so here is the code of both plugin

2nd one:
`plugin.js`

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'linkfile', {
    icons: 'linkfile',
    lang: [ 'zh', 'en'],
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand( 'linkfileDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'linkfileDialog' ) );
        editor.ui.addButton( 'linkfile', {
                label : 'Image/video url',
            command: 'linkfileDialog',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });

        CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'linkfileDialog', this.path + 'dialogs/linkfile.js' );
    }
});
```

`dialogs/linkfile.js

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'linkfileDialog', function( editor ) {

    return {
                    title : 'Image/video url',
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 75,
        contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab-basic',
                label: 'Basic Settings',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'linkfileURL',
                              label : 'Paste video(mp4/webm) or image (jpg/png/gif) URL',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
      onOk: function() {
      var dialog = this;
            var url=dialog.getValueOf( 'tab-basic', 'linkfileURL').trim();
      var fileExtension = url.split('.').pop()
      var content = '';
      var blackList = ['iplogger', '2no.co','bc.vc', 'yip.su', 'bit.do','soo.gd', '7.ly', 'tiny.cc', 'zzb.bz', 'cur.lv', 'shorte.st', 'adf', 'bit', 'biturl', 'rurl.co']
      for (i=0; blackList.length >= i; i++){
        if (url.includes(blackList[i])) {
          alert( 'Forbidden url');
                return false;
        }
      }
      if (fileExtension == "mp4" || fileExtension == "webm") {
        content = '<video style="max-height:400px;" width="100%" controls> <source src="' + url + '"type="video/mp4"></video>'
      } else if (fileExtension == "jpg" || fileExtension == "png" || fileExtension == "gif" ||
        fileExtension == "jpeg") {
        content = '<img src="' + url +'"/>';
        } else {
          alert( 'Incorrect url');
                return false;
        }
          var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(content);
          editor.insertElement(element);
        }
    };
});
```

and the last one

`plugin.js`

```
( function() {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'rsembbed',
        {
            lang: ['en'],
            init: function( editor )
            {
                editor.ui.addButton( 'Rsembbed',
                    {
                        label : "Twitter/instagram embbed",
                        toolbar : 'insert',
                        command : 'rsembbed',
                        icon : this.path + 'icons/rsembbed.png'
                    });

                editor.addCommand( 'rsembbed', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'rsembbedDialog' ) );
                CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'rsembbedDialog', this.path + 'dialogs/rsembbed.js' );
            }
        });
})();
```

`dialogs/rsembbed.js`

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'rsembbedDialog', function( editor ) {

    return {
                    title : 'Twitter/instagram url',
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 75,
        contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab-basic',
                label: 'Basic Settings',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'rsembbedURL',
                              label : 'Paste twitter or instagram URL',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
      onOk: function() {
        var dialog = this;
              var url=dialog.getValueOf( 'tab-basic', 'rsembbedURL').trim();
        var content = '';
        if (url.indexOf("twitter.com") > 0){
          $.ajax({
              url: "https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=" + url,
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(res){
                content = res.html
                console.log(content)
                var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(content);
                editor.insertElement(element); }
            });
            }  else {
              alert( 'Incorrect url');
                    return false;
            }
          }
        };
      });
```

If you have any idea of a path I could explore because I'm struggling with this problem since yesterday ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you use **turbolink** ?

i think your problem is turbolink:load instead of ready function

try to use

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', () ->
  ....
)
```

and

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:before-cache", function() {
  ....
});
```

Comment: Yes I use turbolink and I always use `turbolinks:load` but in this case I'm not using the ready function and it was working well before